# Navigate between views in Xamarin (visual studio) PCL project

Tags: c#, forms, button, xamarin, onclick

I cant find a way to implement an onClick event on a button that will allow the application to navigate between the login and the second view.

How can I do that ?

Here is what i did

I created a method in my LoginViewModel.cs file that should redirect me to the second view.

```
 class LoginViewModel
{
 private async Task SecondView_Click()
        {
            App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SecondView());
        }
}
```

Then I've defined a BindingContext in my Login.cs

```
 public partial class Login : ContentPage
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new LoginViewModel();
        }
    }
```

Then I define a button in my Login.xaml that has a binded command property

```
 <StackLayout
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Entry StyleId="UsernameEntry"
               Placeholder="Username"
               Text="{Binding Username}" />
        <Entry StyleId="PasswordEntry"
               Placeholder="password"
               Text="{Binding Password}" />
        <Button 
            StyleId="btn_connexion"
            Text="Connexion"
            Command="{Binding connexion}" />
        <Button 
            StyleId="btn_testSecondView"
            Text="Test 2nd View"
                Command="{Binding SecondView_Click}"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: which is the error?

Comment: no error, when i click on it it just doesnt switch to the second view. I may have badly implemented the method but i dont what is the correct way to do it.

Comment: App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SecondView()); if you set a breakpoint here, it is reached?

Comment: No, it's not. I've been looking for another property that would looks like the command one but nothing so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

PAGE 1 XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestRelativeLayout.MyPage1"
             Title="TabbedPage">
             <StackLayout>
                <Button Clicked="Handle_Clicked" Text = "Press">

        </Button>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

PAGE 1 XAML.CS

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestRelativeLayout
{
    public partial class MyPage1 : ContentPage
    {
        public MyPage1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyPage2());
        }
    }
}
```

Try to remove

```
private async Task
```

and use

```
void

private async Task SecondView_Click()
        {
            App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SecondView());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did.

I found that there is a "clicked" property on  that prompt an intellisense dropdown with a "new event handler".

```
<StackLayout
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Entry StyleId="UsernameEntry"
               Placeholder="Username"
               Text="{Binding Username}" />
        <Entry StyleId="PasswordEntry"
               Placeholder="password"
               Text="{Binding Password}" />
        <Button 
            StyleId="btn_connexion"
            Text="Connexion"
            Clicked="connexion" />
        <Button 
            StyleId="btn_testSecondView"
            Text="Test 2nd View"
                Clicked="SecondView_Click"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
```

Once i did that it created a method in the code behind "Login.xaml.cs".

From there I just paste the navigation method and it worked

```
private async Task SecondView_Click()
        {
            App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SecondView());
        }
```

The fact that it is a PCL project makes it difficult to find the right information because everything you find on the internet concerns the ios/android solution and not the portable solution.